# Order/precedence of rails validation checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get my head around the order/precedence with which Rails processes validation checks. Let me give an example.

In my model class I have these validation checks and custom validation methods:

```
class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord

  # Check both dates are actually provided when user submits a form
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :end_time, presence: true

  # Check datetime format with validates_timeliness gem: https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness
  validates_datetime :start_time
  validates_datetime :end_time

  # Custom method to ensure duration is within limits
  def duration_restrictions

    # Next line returns nil if uncommented so clearly no start and end dates data which should have been picked up by the first validation checks
    # raise duration_mins.inspect # Returns nil

    # Use same gem as above to calculate duration of a SupportSession
    duration_mins = TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_minutes

    if duration_mins == 0
      errors[:base] << 'A session must last longer than 1 minute'
    end

    if duration_mins > 180
      errors[:base] << 'A session must be shorter than 180 minutes (3 hours)'
    end
  end
```

The problem is that Rails doesn't seem to be processing the 'validates presence' or 'validates_datetime' checks first to make sure that the data is there in the first place for me to work with. I just get this error on the line where I calculate duration_mins (because there is no start_time and end_time provided:

```
undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a reason for this or have I just run into a bug? Surely the validation checks should make sure that values for start_time and end_time are present, or do I have to manually check the values in all of my custom methods? That's not very DRY.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails will run all validations in the order specified even if any validation gets failed. Probably you need to validate datetime only if the values are present.

You can do this in two ways,

1. Check for the presence of the value before validating,

   ```
   validates_datetime :start_time, if: -> { start_time.present? }
   validates_datetime :end_time, if: -> { end_time.present? }
   ```
2. Allows a nil or empty string value to be valid,

   ```
   validates_datetime :start_time, allow_blank: true
   validates_datetime :end_time, allow_blank: true
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way, add this line right after `def duration_restrictions`

```
return if ([ start_time, end_time ].find(&:blank?))
```

Rails always validate custom method first.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I understand it Rails processes every single validation check in the model, regardless of whether any one of them fails. It seems bit counterintuitive to me but I'm sure there's a good reason. What was confusing me is that if the first validation check, checking whether the field values were present, passes (which it shouldn't do - because they aren't), surely? But now I understand that Rails just continues regardless and processes all other checks, even though the first presence check failed. Hence why other errors were appearing from other functions, confusingly.